# Extract data from one big string with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Consider the following String, which is a table of content extracted from a pdf, like in the following example, two topics can be on one line, there is one line break at the end of each line (like in the example)

```
A — N° 1 2 janvier 2013

TABLE OF CONTENT

Topic à one ......... 30 Second Topic .......... 33
Third - one ......... 3 Topic.with.dots .......... 33
One more line ......................... 27 last topic ...... 34
```

I want to extract the section's name 'Topic à one', 'Second Topic', 'Third -one', 'Topic.with.dots', 'One more line' and 'last topic'

Any insights for a matching regex?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? Please always add a corresponding tag to any regex question. Thanks!

Comment: Which characters are allowed in a section name?

Comment: @Tim A topic can contains the following characters a A à . -

Comment: Define what "this is a String, they are not multiple lines" means? A string can contain multiple lines if it has line-breaks. Is the sample one long string that actually wraps but you broke it to fit in the page, or does it have line-breaks internally, resulting in the displayed text?

Comment: @the Tin Man It has line breaks like in my example, I will edit my question to remove the ambiguity

Comment: You added a à, but didn't adjust your expected extractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
string = "A — N° 1 2 janvier 2013

TABLE OF CONTENT

Topic à one ......... 30 Second Topic .......... 33
Third - one ......... 3 Topic.with.dots .......... 33
One more line ......................... 27 last topic ...... 34"
puts string.scan(/(\p{l}[\p{l} \.-]*)\s+\.+\s+\d+/i).flatten
```

This does what you want. It also matches single letter titles.

Comment: I'd suggest to add a `?` after the first `+`, and maybe use `[ \t]` instead of `\s`, and use `/i`.

Comment: @Qtax Why [ \t] instead of \s?

Comment: So that a match can't spend multiple lines (in case of some odd text).

Comment: @Chris works fine, except that it doesn't handle special characters like à - I edited the question to reflect this requirement, i will probably find the solution myself, thanks

Comment: @denisjacquemin I've adjusted it for your special chars. You didn't adjust your expectations; I take it you want to match 'Topic à one` and not 'Topic one'.... These are my first lines of ruby ever ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following (unoptimized yet) regex works on your example:

```
(?i)(?=[A-Z])(?:\.[A-Z-]+|[A-Z -]+)+\b
```

It needs improvements, though, for example if non-ASCII letters should be matched, and there are some possible performance optimizations that depend on the exact regex flavor being used.

[See it on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hP8qW8).

For Ruby 2, I would suggest `/(?=\p{L})(?:\.[\p{L}-]++|[\p{L} -]+)+\b/`

Answer (score 1):

```
string.scan(/(\S.*?)\s+\.{2,}\s+\d+/).flatten
# =>
[
  "Topic one",
  "Second Topic",
  "Third one",
  "Topic.with.dots",
  "One more line",
  "last topic"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @sawa's:

```
puts text.scan(/([a-zA-Z .]+?) \.\.++ \d+/).flatten.map(&:strip)
# >> Topic one
# >> Second Topic
# >> Third one
# >> Topic.with.dots
# >> One more line
# >> last topic
```

(I like his pattern better though.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution in Perl:

```
 $ cat tmp
 Topic one ......... 30 Second Topic .......... 33 Third one ......... 3   Topic.with.dots ..........   33 One more line ......................... 27 last topic ...... 34


$ cat tmp  | perl -ne 'while (m/((?:\w|[. ])+?) [.]+ \d+/g) { print "$1\n" }' 
Topic one
Second Topic
Third one
 Topic.with.dots
One more line
last topic
```

A little explanation of what I am doing here, the inner set of parens `(?:...)` are non capturing, so they are only for grouping, and they group a word-char (`\w`) or a space or dot `[. ]` and then, since you have more dots, the match is non-greedy `+?` and the whole match goes into `$1`, which is printed.

HTH

**--EDIT--**

Ruby has almost all constructs of Perl, including regex, and it is a 
straight forward conversion! (not sure why it had to be voted down!)
FWIW, here it is in Ruby:

```
while ARGF.gets
  puts $_.scan(/((?:\w|[. ])+?) [.]+ \d+/)
end
```

Comment: @theTinMan Come on, a regex is a regex. It's usually not a big problem to use a regex from one language in another.

Comment: Onigmo is only a subset of PCRE.